# Android device update for G1

Tags: java, android

I am using android G1 phone and now I have upgraded my SDK to 1.5 and I want to run my application on a physical device, but when I connect my phone to PC I'm able to install my app only when I'm selecting 1.1 SDK but not when selected 1.5 .

So is there any updates required for the device so I can proceed with 1.5 SDK? Also, if possible can you provide with a proper link? That would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An update for your phone will be pushed OTA by your operator, just wait. If it is a dev phone look at [HTC pages](http://www.htc.com/www/support/android/adp.html).

Comment: I am having a T mobile G1 not the dev phone but when can i expect that update .

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the US or UK you can find instructions on how to force-upgrade [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-manually-install-android-15-cupcake-us-version). I did it on mine and it went fine.